# Regex remove character folloing n characters

Tags: c#, regex

I am a bit out of exercise after two years not coding.
I have thousand of lines in a txt file. All similar to this one:

```
X0 Y0 S-0.30
X0 Y0 S-0.21
X0 Y0 S-0.08
```

I need to remove the S-x.xx value from all lines. So only the X Y and the relevant values will be saved for each line.

I have attempted with Regex

```
if (Line.Contains("S"))
        {
           Regex rgx = new Regex(@"S\d+(\.\d+)?");
            Line = rgx.Replace(Line, "");
        }
        return Line;
```

But I am not getting the result I expect. Any hint will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: You are missing a `-` between `S` and `\d+`. According to your samples, `S.*` would also be sufficient.

Comment: Thank you. That's solved my issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Appreciate that you really just want to remove the final third term, which begins with `S`.  Just try replacing the pattern `\sS.*$` with empty string:

```
Regex rgx = new Regex(@"\sS.*$");
string Line = "X0 Y0 S-0.30";
Line = rgx.Replace(Line, "");
Console.WriteLine(Line);

X0 Y0
```

### Demo

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following RegEx : [`(X\d+ Y\d+).*`](https://regex101.com/r/w1gqsu/1)

And use `$1`.

`X` matches the character `X` literally (case sensitive)

`\d+` matches a digit (equal to `[0-9]`) one or more times

`Y` matches the characters `Y` literally (case sensitive)

`\d+` matches a digit (equal to `[0-9]`) one or more times

Answer (score 1):

You may use

```
var result = Regex.Replace(s, @"\s+S-\d+(?:\.\d+)?", string.Empty);
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/OsiRxn/1)

- `\s+` - 1+ whitespaces
- `S-` - `S-` substring
- `\d+(?:\.\d+)?` - a number pattern:

  - `\d+` - 1+ digits
  - `(?:\.\d+)?` - an optional sequence:
  - `\.` - dot
  - `\d+` - 1+ digits.